# using for loop iteration (decrement or increment )based on user input in C program

Tags: arrays, c

i am writing code to do some operation with array.
requirement is to read the array and set the value.
if user set input as U need to start the array from index to last and copy the values.
if user set input as D need to start the array from index last to zero index and copy the values.

except looping condition everything is same inside the loop. so trying to optimize the code into single loop is it possible in C like below or any other suggestion .

```
char input = 'U';

if (input == 'U')
   for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
else if (input == 'D')
   for (size_t i = M; i < 0; i--)
  {
     //parsing logic with index;
  }
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/UFFehw

Comment: when input == 'D' **i** should be **M-1** during initialization and  **i<0** should be **i<=0** while checking the condition because we want to access the very first index as well isn't it?

Comment: 'trying to optimize the code into single loop' AKA 'trying to make testing and debugging more difficult':((

Comment: Please format this sloppy code. It is disrespectful to post such and expect others to read it.

Comment: So, two answers.  One got deleted, the other was buggy.  See my comment above and note that writing 'clever optimizations' is not conducive to developing reliable apps.  Test/debug takes up a very large proportion of development time and it is very rare that effort spent on dubious 'optimizations' is worth the pain.

Answer (score 1):

We can use single loop and can use **start**, **end** & **flag** variables to achieve this.

**start** denotes the starting of loop

**end** denotes the ending of loop

**flag** denotes the increment and decrement

```
char input = 'U';

size_t flag = 1;
size_t start = 0, end = M;

//if input is 'D' default if set to match input U
if (input = 'D'){
    start = M;
    end = 0
    flag = -1
}
//single loop
for (size_t i = start ; ; i+=flag){
    if(input == 'D' && i <= end) break;
    else if(input =='U' && i >= end)break;
    //parsing logic with index
}
```

Comment: when input is D
the condition in loop becomes false in first iteration itself.
say M = 10
for (size_t i =10; 10 < 0; i+=flag)

10 < 0 becomes false not all at entering into the loop